# What package should i use for interfaces which are domain entity methods arguments?

Tags: domain-driven-design, clean-architecture

I have domain entity Task (it's to do list app) and this entity has a method saveToFile() which takes two arguments - interface ToFileSaver and string fileName. I know this interface should be placed in a domain layer and its implementations in a infrastructure layer but what names should i use for these packages? Ports and adapters?

Answer (score 0):

The parameter types of the entity methods usually belong to these entities. Thus I would place them in the same package as the entity. I would only place them in other packages if they belong to other parts of the domain that belong to another domain concept, e.g. user management.

The implementations are placed outside as you said.

But it seems that you place persistence issues in the domain layer. Instead of giving the entities a `Task.saveToFile(ToFileSaver)` method you should rather define a `TaskRepositoy.persist(Task)` method.

Comment: Saving to a file isn't my persistence method. I'm using database (Spring Data JPA + H2). I have service SaveTaskToFileService which gets task from db by id an invoke methods save from it.